# Problem with losing internet connection in 13.10

Tags: wireless

I just got ubuntu 13.10. It works just fine, but the internet connection gets interrupted every so often when I try to load a page from any given websites (after being connected for maybe 10 or 15 minutes).

It's searching and then I get an message saying that I have a problem with my internet connection, thus won't open anything.

I have to restart my computer every time to refresh it. The wireless connection shows it's working, so what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

May be your lan card is not supporting 100 base connection.

first run this command in your terminal sudo mii-tool type password.

eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok

You set your eth0 on 10base. Run this command in terminal

sudo mii-tool -F 10baseT-HD

Note :- (This command will set your lan connection 10base) After that your connection will be lost.