# Wifi loses internet connection after awhile

Tags: wireless, 16.04, lenovo, realtek

I just purchased a new lenovo ideapad 100 (100-15IBD) with a realtek wireless adapter. lspci showed me this :- 03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Although Ethernet is working, wifi connection works for awhile but then stops to load in pages without any sign of disconnection. The signal is pretty good (near 70%).

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (with cinnamon desktop). Updated kernel to 4.6, disabled power management and ipv6, still the problem persists. It works for awhile I pause working and then when I return, after a little time want to open a new tab and it will never come, only if I disconnect/connect... The period for which it remains connected is very much random, couldn't figure out what could cause the internet stop.

Here is the wireless-info.tar.gz: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_wNb7GliwQWTFpLXh5YnV6ZTQ

As I see I'm not alone with this problem and the others didn't got answers neither.

[Wifi losing connection randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557739/wifi-losing-connection-randomly)

[Problem with losing internet connection in 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413513/problem-with-losing-internet-connection-in-13-10)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/709116/losing-internet-connection-with-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: For me it doesn't disconnect just the internet access goes away, in the network manager it remains to be connected, no disconnected message. Anyhow, thanks for pointing to that thread, will try its solution.

Comment: The problem amy look different, but the solution is same.